# Flutter AnimatedList with Provider Pattern

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-animatedlist

I have model which implements ChangeNotifier

```
class DataModel with ChangeNotifier{
   List<Data> data = List<Data>();

   void addData(Data data){
      data.add(data);
      notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

and a ListView which listens to those changes:

```
class DataListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<DataModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: model.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(model.data[index].value);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

so far so good, when an item is added to the list in the model, the change notification triggers a rebuild of the Listview and I see the new data. But I cant wrap my head around using this with a AnimatedList instead of a ListView. Preferably id like to keep my model as it is, seeing as the animation is a concern of the ui and not of my logic.

The changenotifier always gives me a uptodate version of my data, but what i really need is a "item added" or "item removed" notification.

Is there a best practice way of doing this?

Comment: I am exactly same spot, it doesn't seem like a good fit with provider pattern and moreover - I am doing sorting on the entire list and would like some build in animation for stuff moving around . did you find any workable solution for that ?

Answer (score 4):

I recently started to learn Flutter and was surprised to find that this topic isn't covered properly anywhere. I came up with two approaches which I called Basic and Advanced. Let's start from Basic. It's named like that because Provider is called within the same widget where AnimatedList is built.

```dart
class Users extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];

  int get length => _list.length;

  operator [](index) => _list[index];

  int add() {
    final int index = length;
    _list.add('$index');
    notifyListeners();
    return index;
  }

  String removeAt(int index) {
    String user = _list.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
    return user;
  }
}

class BasicApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BasicApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Users(), child: AnimatedListDemo()));
  }
}

class AnimatedListDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  AnimatedListDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void addUser(Users users) {
    final int index = users.add();
    _listKey.currentState!.insertItem(index, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  void deleteUser(Users users, int index) {
    String user = users.removeAt(index);
    _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(
      index,
      (context, animation) {
        return SizeTransition(sizeFactor: animation, child: _buildItem(users, user));
      },
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(Users users, String user, [int? removeIndex]) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ValueKey<String>(user),
      title: Text(user),
      leading: const CircleAvatar(
        child: Icon(Icons.person),
      ),
      trailing: (removeIndex != null)
          ? IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () => deleteUser(users, removeIndex),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Users users = Provider.of<Users>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Basic AnimatedList Provider Demo'),
      ),
      body: AnimatedList(
        key: _listKey,
        initialItemCount: users.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: _buildItem(users, users[index], index),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => addUser(users),
        tooltip: 'Add an item',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Advanced approach differs in that it encapsulates AnimatedListState. I took this idea from Flutter's [AnimatedList docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html).

```dart
typedef RemovedItemBuilder = Widget Function(
    String user, BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation);

class Users extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();
  final RemovedItemBuilder _removedItemBuilder;

  Users(this._removedItemBuilder);

  int get length => _list.length;

  operator [](index) => _list[index];

  GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> get listKey => _listKey;

  int add() {
    final int index = length;
    _list.add('$index');
    _listKey.currentState!.insertItem(index, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    notifyListeners();
    return index;
  }

  String removeAt(int index) {
    String user = _list.removeAt(index);
    _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(
      index,
      (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
        return _removedItemBuilder(user, context, animation);
      },
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    notifyListeners();
    return user;
  }
}

class AdvancedApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AdvancedApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: AnimatedListDemo());
  }
}

class AnimatedListDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnimatedListDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _buildItem(BuildContext context, String user, [int? removeIndex]) {
    Users users = Provider.of<Users>(context, listen: false);
    return ListTile(
      key: ValueKey<String>(user),
      title: Text(user),
      leading: const CircleAvatar(
        child: Icon(Icons.person),
      ),
      trailing: (removeIndex != null)
          ? IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () => users.removeAt(removeIndex),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Users((user, context, animation) {
      return SizeTransition(sizeFactor: animation, child: _buildItem(context, user));
    }), child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Advanced AnimatedList Provider Demo'),
      ),
      body: Consumer<Users>(builder: (BuildContext context, Users users, _){
        return AnimatedList(
          key: users.listKey,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          initialItemCount: users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: _buildItem(context, users[index], index),
            );
          },
        );
      }),
      floatingActionButton: const AddButtonSeparateWidget(),
    ));
  }
}

class AddButtonSeparateWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddButtonSeparateWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Users users = Provider.of<Users>(context, listen: false);
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: users.add,
      tooltip: 'Add an item',
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }
}
```

All code is published on [Github](https://github.com/vogdb/flutter_animated_list_provider). Now I want to elaborate a bit on your proposition of having "item added" or "item removed" notifications. From what I understand it goes against Flutter's philosophy where widget is a UI config. When a widget's state changes, Flutter diffs against its previous state and magically applies the diff to UI. That's why I didn't use "item added", "item removed" notifications in my implementations. However I think it should be possible to do because I saw a similar approach in [Firestore subscription to document changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) although for now I can't figure how to implement the same with Provider. Provider's documentation is kind of poor. After a careful reading I can't say how to implement partial updates with Provider. May be ProxyProvider with its `update` could help or may be ListenableProvider. Let me know if you could find the solution to your proposition.

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of my trial.
It's a riverpod version, but I think it's the same for providers.

There are two points.

1. Initialize the state in the parent widget of the widget that uses
   AnimatedList.
2. Add / delete AnimatedList and add / delete states asynchronously by using async.

#### main.dart

```
import 'package:animatedlist_riverpod_sample/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/all.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends HookWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todoList = useProvider(todoListProvider.state);
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Todo[${todoList.length}]')), body: TodoListView());
  }
}

class TodoListView extends HookWidget {
  TodoListView({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  final todoList = useProvider(todoListProvider.state);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedList(
      key: _listKey,
      initialItemCount: todoList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) =>
          _buildItem(todoList[index], animation, index, context),
    );
  }

  Slidable _buildItem(Todo todo, Animation<double> animation, int index, BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
      child: SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: animation,
          axis: Axis.vertical,
          child: ListTile(title: Text(todo.description), subtitle: Text(todo.id), onTap: () => {})),
      secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Delete',
          color: Colors.red,
          icon: Icons.delete,
          onTap: () {
            _listKey.currentState.removeItem(
                index, (context, animation) => _buildItem(todo, animation, index, context),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
            _removeItem(context, todo);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _removeItem(BuildContext context, Todo todo) async {
    await Future.delayed(
        Duration(milliseconds: 200), () => context.read(todoListProvider).remove(todo));
  }
}
```

#### provider.dart

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/all.dart';

final todoListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TodoList>((ref) {
  return TodoList([
    Todo(id: '0', description: 'Todo1'),
    Todo(id: '1', description: 'Todo2'),
    Todo(id: '2', description: 'Todo3'),
  ]);
});

class Todo {
  Todo({
    this.id,
    this.description,
  });

  final String id;
  final String description;
}

class TodoList extends StateNotifier<List<Todo>> {
  TodoList([List<Todo> initialTodos]) : super(initialTodos ?? []);

  void add(String description) {
    state = [
      ...state,
      Todo(description: description),
    ];
  }

  void remove(Todo target) {
    state = state.where((todo) => todo.id != target.id).toList();
  }
}
```

sample repository is [here](https://github.com/nmaruy27/animatedlist_riverpod_sample).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I'm adding this here if anyone stumbles to this question and hasn't found a proper solution.

I wanted some form of height transition working on list of items added to a sidebar I had. It was basically a basket for a purchase. I also use Provider as a state management solution.

`AnimatedList` was not a great option here, because you need to control the number of items using the `GlobalKey`. My functions for adding an item and removing an item were elsewhere in the application (product cards etc.), so hooking them to the key would have been too complex.

So instead I opted in animating a `Column()` widget that was wrapping my child items, with `AnimatedSize()` that does as it's named, animates the height automatically.

I then added an animation to the list item widgets I had. This provides me with a height transition when I add an item to the list, and the list item itself fades in nicely with it.

Here is an example:

```dart
class PurchaseRowItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const PurchaseRowItem({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  final PurchaseRow item;

  @override
  State<PurchaseRowItem> createState() => _PurchaseRowItemState();
}

class _PurchaseRowItemState extends State<PurchaseRowItem> {
  bool _visible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Opacity needs to start from 0 and transition to 1
    // so we set it in initState by waiting 10ms
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
      setState(() {
        _visible = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AnimatedSize(
      curve: Curves.linear,
      // Alignment is important if you want the list to flow from top to bottom so it doesn't jump when adding items
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          for (var item in purchase.rows)
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _visible ? 1 : 0,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              child: Dismissible(
                child: Container() // Add your list item here
              ),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```